# Returning rows of aggregate results from single SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have a MySQL table containing a column to store time and another to store a value associated with that time.

```
time | value
------------
 1   |  0.5     
 3   |  1.0     
 4   |  1.5 
.... | .....
```

The events are not periodic, i.e., the time values do not increment by fix interval.

As there are large number of rows (> 100000), for the purpose of showing the values in a graph I would like to be able to aggregate (mean) the values for an interval of fixed size over the entire length of time for which the data is available. So basically the output should consist of pairs of interval and mean values.

Currently, I am splitting the total time interval into fixed chunks of time, executing individual aggregate queries for that interval and collecting the results in application code (Java). Is there a way to do all of these steps in SQL. Also, I am currently using MySQL but am open to other databases that might support an efficient solution.

Comment: @cularis Thanks for fixing the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT FLOOR(time / x) AS Inter, AVG(value) AS Mean
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY Inter;
```

Where `x` is your interval of fixed size.

Comment: I agree with the idea of grouping by `FLOOR(time / x)`, but I don't think the result of that expression as interval identifier would be quite clear. Something like `MIN(time) AS StartTime, MAX(time) AS EndTime` (yes, two values) might be friendlier to the user, I think.

Comment: Can this idea also be used if time is not instantaneous but stored as two columns `start` and `end`? And what of the case where some of the events cross the interval boundaries?

Answer (score 2):

I've usually solved this through a "period" table, with all the valid times in it, and an association with the period on which I report.

For instance:

```
time      day   week month year
1           1      1     1 2001 
2           1      1     1 2001
....
999         7      52   12 2010
```

You can then join your time to the "period" table time, and use AVG.